# Local Login - what is the real meaning in TELNET?

Tags: networking, telnet

I am studying about TELNET in Computer Networks Course and having an exam tomorrow. When starting it, I saw a difference between Local Login and Remote Login. In one book, When a user logs into a local system, it is called local login. As a user types at a terminal or at a workstation running a terminal emulator, the keystrokes are accepted by the terminal driver. The terminal driver passes the characters to the operating system. The operating system, in turn, interprets the combination of characters and invokes the desired application program or utility

From another book, When a user logs into a local time-sharing system, it is called local login. As a user types at a terminal or at a workstation running a terminal emulator, the keystrokes are accepted by the terminal driver. The terminal driver passes the characters to the operating system. The operating system, in turn, interprets the combination of characters and invokes the desired application program or utility

Online website, "In local log-in, the user terminal is directly connected to the target computer; in remote log-in, the user computer is connected to the target computer through the Internet."

Not understanding the actual meaning of it! Why? At my college, We students use computers to access the Remote Server using Putty terminal to execute our code using the Remote Server, with each student assigned a login and password. This is I think Remote Login. Correct me If I'm wrong?

But, what I am thinking is that the Remote Server Computer: When a person logins into it, since it's the time-sharing system, is it called Local Login? Or when a normal student logins into the Computer (say Windows), is it Local Login?

Comment: Local is your computer, remote, the thing in front of you. Everything else is remote.

Answer (score 2):

TELNET is a protocol for connecting to a command console over TCP/IP. Whether the destination is local or routing across a network doesn't matter.

Local login often uses interfaces with limited reach, e.g. local video and keyboard, or a serial terminal.

> We students use computers to access the Remote Server using Putty terminal to execute our code using the Remote Server, with each student assigned a login and password.

Assuming you're using Putty's SSH or TELNET mode, that's remote login over a network. Putty also supports using a serial interface which would most probably be a local login.

Note that you could also extend a serial interface using a pair of modems (or COM servers) connected across the globe. That login would in fact be remote but seen as local from the server.

> When a person logins into it, since it's the time-sharing system, is it called Local Login?

It's about the technology (and perhaps the interface) that you use to log in. If your terminal is connected directly, the login is local. If the connection runs across a network, it's remote.

> when a normal student logins into the Computer (say Windows), is it Local Login?

When you use the connected (local) monitor and (local) keyboard, it's local. You can also login remotely using RDP or various other protocols and tools.

The local vs remote login distinction may have been important several decades ago back when remote functionality was rather limited and *remote* was somewhat advanced. Today, you can log into a tiny Arduino across the planet.

Answer (score 1):

> Online website, "In local log-in, the user terminal is directly connected to the target computer; in remote log-in, the user computer is connected to the target computer through the Internet."

The quotes from your study material sound positively ancient; they still talk about "[terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100)" that were all wired to a single computer that was elsewhere in the building, which is rarely if ever seen these days.

So when the quote says "user terminal", you can read it as "In local login, the user *display and keyboard* is directly connected to the target computer".

> But, what I am thinking is that the Remote Server Computer: When a person logins into it, since it's the time-sharing system, is it called Local Login? Or when a normal student logins into the Computer (say Windows), is it Local Login?

It depends on how many computers and/or networks (zero or ≥1) are between you and the Server Computer:

- If you log in through a non-computer device that's directly wired to the Server Computer (e.g. a directly connected VGA monitor and keyboard), then that's Local Login.
- If you use **some other computer** to log in to the Server Computer (through a network or through a serial line), then that's Remote Login.

So when you log in to your personal Windows machine, that's a Local Login. If you then use PuTTY to SSH into a second machine, you're doing Remote Login.

(And if you break into the university's server room and attach a monitor and keyboard to the server in question, *that's a Local Login* even if you're doing to a server.)

> But, what I am thinking is that the Remote Server Computer: When a person logins into it, since it's the time-sharing system, is it called Local Login?

No, because you reached it through *another* time-sharing system: your own PC.

(Even if it's not really seen as a multi-user device, your PC nevertheless runs a "time-sharing" OS that runs multiple processes which could belong to multiple users, as opposed to batch-processing systems from the 1960s.)

Again, keep in mind the historical context of your quotes. These days each and every person has their own computer, but a text that specifically talks about [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) (which weren't PCs – they were just text-based monitors), is talking about *many such terminals* being wired to one local Big Computer.

So in that context, instead of everyone in the lab having their own PCs, you'd have everyone *locally* time-sharing the same computer first – and only then connecting from it to somewhere remote. (Well, some university labs might still have that, but these days they call it "thin client" and it has multiple VGA monitors wired to the server.)

> what is the real meaning in TELNET?

"Telnet" simply refers to one specific protocol used for remote login. You most likely use SSHv2 with PuTTY, but you must've seen Telnet as an option (below the hostname input) – both achieve the exact same thing; both allow you to access a Remote Server and Do Things Remotely.

The only special thing about Telnet is that it's a very old protocol in Internet terms<sup>1</sup>; so old that it **predates TCP/IP** – it's one of the original ARPANET protocols from the "NCP" era that survived the "NCP"→TCP/IP transition, together with FTP.

(I think it's *the* original ARPANET protocol, even – for a brief time it was what ARPANET did, before the idea of generic "sockets" came along.)

Telnet is still in occasional use because it's a very simple protocol programmatically; 90% of Telnet is "send ASCII over a TCP connection", which is the simplest possible thing you can *do* with TCP.

<sup>1</sup> (The above is specifically regarding Internet/ARPANET. Various other networks existed at the same time, such as X.25, and Telnet is certainly not the first "remote access" protocol in general; but for a long time, if you were accessing a server *over Internet*, you would've most likely used Telnet for that.)